# Intellij with Google Cloud Tools Javadoc

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-intellij

Should there by Javadoc (ctrl+q) for Google App Engine Standard Environment methods in Intellij with Google Cloud Tools? I'm running on a new install of both the tools and Intellij and there is no documentation for any GAE methods/classes. Could I have missed a step in the installation? Everything else, such as deploying and running on GAE, works fine.

Comment: The [Google Cloud Tools for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8079-google-cloud-tools) plugin does not affect the Javadoc on the App Engine Java API, that comes from the downloaded App Engine API JARs when you depend on them via your build system.

How are you adding the API dependency? And what classes/methods in particular would you expect to have Javadoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the sdk from Google https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download, then in Project Settings>Libraries>appengine-api-1.0-sdk-* added the \docs\javadoc folder from the downloaded zip